# LifecycleException: Failed to start component deploying war in Tomcat

Tags: hibernate, rest, tomcat, jpa, spring-boot

I implemented restful api with Spring Boot. It works when I start the application within Spring Boot Suite with embeded Tomcat server. However when I tried to deploy the war to Tomcat 7, I got the following errors:

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/cgweb]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/djiao/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/cgweb/LICENSE (Is a directory)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cgweb]]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /Users/djiao/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/cgweb.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina
].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cgweb]]
```

I know there are probably hundreds of similar type of posts. After I have been researching for more than 2 days, here are the major causes of such problem.

1. Tomcat version does not match java compiler version.

I compiled with java 7 and used Tomcat 7 for deploy. I made sure I set jre path for JAVA_HOME not jdk path.

2. Conflict between jpa 2.0 and 2.1 (related to the Foreign key error).

I had both in my dependency and removed 2.0.

3. Version mismatch between hibernate-entitymanger and hibernate-core.

Checked the dependency hierarchy of the pom, they are both 4.3.11.Final.

4. Deployed by copying the war to webapp folder manually.

Tried to deploy in Tomcat Manager UI.

None of these applied to my case. Tried everything and yet nothing worked. Since I am using Spring Boot, most of the configuration was done automatically. I do not have a web.xml. I have the following annotations before main Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.model"}) 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.mdacc.rists.cghub.ws.repository"})
```

In application.properties, I have the following lines other than datasource configs.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

Any other possible reason that could cause the deploy failure?

Comment: Check if you have any hibernate or JPA related jar files in tomcat server lib or common directory, that takes precedence over the once you are packaging in your WEB-INF/lib. And just to be sure do a clean build and clean the tomcat working dir and restart.

Comment: Sorry, but there is only ONE thing that _java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey_ means. You have a JPA API v2.0 jar in the CLASSPATH at runtime. Still. So print out the runtime system.classpath

Comment: Try running Tomcat with`-verbose:class`. It'll show you where the JPA 2.0 classes are being loaded from

Comment: @Neil Stockton How do I print out the runtime system.classpath?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I ran `startup.sh -verbose:class`, but nothing is printed out in catalina.[date].log about classes. Where should I look for that information?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I did `maven clean` and `maven install` and still the same. Checked the tomcat lib directory but there is nothing related to jpa there.

Comment: @ddd I hope the war doesn't have multiple versions of JPA/hibernate jars? :)

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu When I first got the error, I did have both jpa 2.0 and 2.1 in my maven dependency, but I took out 2.0 since then.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I just print out the list of jars in my war. Surprisingly, I still have jpa 2.0 there. I deleted in my maven dependency why did it still get in there. Plus, I did `maven clean` and rebuild. How do I take it out completely?

Comment: @ddd I think maven clean should help. Not sure if any existing maven dependency is referring to jpa 2.0 and so it is making into the war file?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu After some investigation, I discovered jpa 2.0 was picked from another project which is one of the dependencies of this application. I did `maven clean` for that dependency package and rebuilt again. And I can deploy it successfully. Can you add an answer and I can close this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the issue, the war file has both jpa 2.0 and 2.1 jar files even after deleting the maven dependency for jpa 2.0 from this project.

The reason being, jpa 2.0 was picked from another project which is one of the dependencies of this project. Doing a maven clean (after removing the jpa 2.0) for that dependency package and rebuilding it again solved the issue.